# Botão aceitar cookie

Tags: javascript, html, button

Apesar de pesquisar a respeito ainda não consegui resolver. Criei um termo de aceite de *cookie* que aparece na `Home` em cima do `header`.

O botão ao clicar ele é fechado normalmente, porém, o que não estou conseguindo fazer, é com que o usuário ao navegar pelo site e votar a *`home`* não apareça mais o termo de *cookie* que já foi aceito. Alguma solução?

Código:

```
<div class="termo-de-cookie">
        <p>Com o objetivo de fornecer um serviço mais personalizado e ágil, armazenamos informações sobre como você usa este site. Esse processo é realizado por meio de pequenos arquivos de textos chamados cookies. Eles contêm pequenas quantidades de informação e são baixados para o seu computador ou outro dispositivo por um servidor deste site. O seu navegador, em seguida, envia esses cookies de volta a cada nova visita. Desta forma, podemos reconhecer e lembrar de suas preferências. Você pode encontrar informações mais detalhadas sobre cookies e como funcionam <a href="/termo-de-cookie/">em nossa página.</a></p>
        <div class="aceitecookie" id="closebtn" onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'">Confirmar e Fechar</div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Você esta usando qual linguagem de back?

Comment: Só estou usando PHP de back, mas utilizo apenas para formulário. Como é um site web institucional, utilizo apenas Js, Html e Css.

Comment: Não estou vendo a parte do cookie em seu código, só tem um `this.parentElement.style.display='none'`, isto apenas oculta o div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

consegui fazer dessa maneira

/front javascript e jquery

```
    <div id="termo-de-cookie" style="display: none"></div>
<script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"
    integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>


    //pegar o IP
    function getIp(callback)
    {
        function response(s)
        {
            callback(window.userip);

            s.onload = s.onerror = null;
            document.body.removeChild(s);
        }

        function trigger()
        {
            window.userip = false;

            var s = document.createElement("script");
            s.async = true;
            s.onload = function() {
                response(s);
            };
            s.onerror = function() {
                response(s);
            };

            s.src = "https://l2.io/ip.js?var=userip";
            document.body.appendChild(s);
        }

        if (/^(interactive|complete)$/i.test(document.readyState)) {
            trigger();
        } else {
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', trigger);
        }
    }
    var ipN;
    getIp(function (ip) {
        window.ipN=ip;
        verificar()
    });
    //verificar se esta apagado
    function verificar(){
        $.post('ver_conf.php?ip='+ipN,
            function (data) {
                if (data.status === 'erro' || data.status === 'erro') {
                    $('#termo-de-cookie').empty();
                    $('#termo-de-cookie').append('<p>Com o objetivo de fornecer um serviço mais personalizado e ágil, armazenamos informações sobre como você usa este site. Esse processo é realizado por meio de pequenos arquivos de textos chamados cookies. Eles contêm pequenas quantidades de informação e são baixados para o seu computador ou outro dispositivo por um servidor deste site. O seu navegador, em seguida, envia esses cookies de volta a cada nova visita. Desta forma, podemos reconhecer e lembrar de suas preferências. Você pode encontrar informações mais detalhadas sobre cookies e como funcionam <a href="/termo-de-cookie/">em nossa página.</a></p>');
                    $('#termo-de-cookie').append('<div class="aceitecookie" id="closebtn" >Confirmar e Fechar</div>');
                    $('#termo-de-cookie').show();
                    //mensagem apagar
                    $('#closebtn').click(function () {
                        $.post('ver_conf.php?ip='+ipN+'&confirmar=1',
                            function (data) {
                                if (data.status === 'sucesso' || data.status === 'Sucesso') {
                                    $('#termo-de-cookie').hide();
                                }
                            });
                    });
                }
            });
    }

</script>
```

back em PHP:

```
 <?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
if (isset($_GET['ip'])) {
    $ip = $_GET['ip'];
    if (isset($_GET['confirmar'])) {
        $ip=$_GET['ip'];
        setcookie($ip, 'confimado');
        echo json_encode(['status'=>'sucesso']);
    } else {
        $ip=preg_replace('@\.@is','_',$ip);
        if (isset($_COOKIE[$ip]) && $_COOKIE[$ip] == 'confimado') {
            echo json_encode(['status' => 'sucesso']);
        } else {
            echo json_encode(['status' => 'erro']);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Se está usando PHP nem precisa desse javascript ai, pegue o IP direto via PHP. Agora sobre usar IP para validar quem aprovou isto pessoalmente acho um problema, muitos provedores de internet tem ip dinamico, logo a aprovação tem que ser algo no navegador do usuário, ou seja um "cookie" (ou outro meio de armazenamento) com tempo de vida longo e que seja renovado a cada novo acesso, isto claro apenas após o usuário confirmar. Outra coisa, aplicar jQuery para algo tão simples assim é desperdício, dá pra usar um JS simples ([viva o Vanilla.js](http://vanilla-js.com/)).